# how to cancel form submit using ngSubmit

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple form like this

```
<form ng-submit="checkValidation()" >
</form>
```

js code

```
function checkValidation() {
   //if some condition then cancel form submission
}
```

Comment: you can write event.preventDefault inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but I think it should work.

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="checkValidation($event)" >
</form>
```

JS:

```
function checkValidation(event) {
   //if some condition then cancel form submission
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using `action="..."` on the form element, then it's up to you to submit the data (ie. ajax) in the first place. You should be able to just `return` early from your function, before the ajax call:

```
function checkValidation() {
   if(formDidntValidate) { return }
   $http.post(...); // post via ajax if data validates
}
```

... or alternatively:

```
function checkValidation() {
    if(formValidated) {
        $http.post(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am using action then?

Comment: Your code sample showed a form without it. If you are using it, you could reconsider, or use the method mr. d suggested, which does seem to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/av1k3uWnNTDbTnv7l5C8?p=preview